# Pusher not decrypting incoming notifications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, encryption, pusher

I am working on a Laravel application which has a React front end. I have notifications setup using pusher which all works fine.

I am trying to use end to end encryption as described here https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/encrypted-channels

In my config/broadcasting.php I have the following

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'useTLS' => true,
            'encryption_master_key' => env('PUSHER_ENCRYPTION_KEY'),
        ],
]
```

In my `.env` `PUSHER_ENCRYPTION_KEY` is set and I can see notifications coming through in the Pusher debug console, encrypted as I would expect.

In my front end I am instantiating Pusher like this

```
const socket = new Pusher(process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY, {
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    authEndpoint: '/api/broadcasting/auth'
});
socket.subscribe('private-encrypted-user.' + props.user.id);

socket.bind('App\\Events\\TaskCreated' , function (data) {            
    console.log(data)
});
```

I can see in my network tab `/api/broadcasting/auth` responds with an extra field now called `shared_secret`. According to the docs this is used to decrypt the incoming notification and decryption should be automatic. When I trigger `App\\Events\\TaskCreated` `console.log(data)` runs but the data is still encrypted.

It also says in the docs `if a client is unable to decrypt a message, it will make another request to your auth endpoint to obtain a new decryption key. If the client is still unable to decrypt the message with the new key, it will throw an error.` yet no errors are thrown and no further requests are made to `/api/broadcasting/auth`

I have enabled `Pusher.logToConsole = true;` and everything looks fine. I even get `"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"private-encrypted-user.2"` which leads me to believe the auth side of things is working as expected.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out!

In my code above I am binding the event to the socket when I need to bind it to the channel. A day wasted but below is working code in case anyone else struggles with the same issue

```
const socket = new Pusher(process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY, {
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    authEndpoint: '/api/broadcasting/auth'
});

const channel = socket.subscribe('private-encrypted-user.' + props.user.id);

channel.bind('App\\Events\\TaskCreated' , function (data) {            
    console.log(data)
});
```